# Is $f$ continuous if for every $p$, there is a sequence $p_n \to p$ such that $f(p_n) \to f(p)$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, continuity

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space and $f : X \rightarrow X$ a function that satisfies the following property: For every $p \in X$ there exists a sequence $\{p_n\}\subset   X$ such that $p_n \rightarrow p $ and $f(p_n) \rightarrow f(p)$. Is $f$ necessarily continuous?

My Answer is 'No'.

Proof:

Since it has not been mentioned that $p_n\neq p$, we can have the constant sequence $p_n=p$ for any $p$. Hence a function from $(\mathbb{R},|\; |)\rightarrow (\mathbb{R},|\; |)$ which has a simple discontinuity at one point satisfy the given property but not continuous. Is this proof correct? If not where I did wrong? Just to make sure.

Comment: I think your argument is correct.

Comment: Your proof is fine. BTW, the claim would still be false if one required that the sequences be injective: Consider $\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$, $x\mapsto \begin{cases}1&\text{if $x\ge 0$}\\0&\text{if $x<0$}\end{cases}$. Then for any $p$, the sequence $p_n=p+\frac1n$ exists with $f(p_n)\to f(p)$.